# Describe the whistle one makes when surprised

Tags: single-word-requests

There are many ways that a person might whistle.  I'm searching for a word that describes the *slow, contemplative* whistle that one might make when digesting new and surprising information.

Is there a better way to describe that whistle that is "*slow, contemplative*"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I single word that describes that whistling sound might not exist, but interjections or exclamations like "whew" as proposed by @Josh61 or the similar "phew" might come close

> **phew**
>
> *exclamation*
>
> a breathy, almost whistling sound used variously to express a sense of
>   relief or to express surprise, disgust, etc.
> <sub>[Collins
>   Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/phew)</sub>

The Oxford Learner's Dictionary uses the following phrase as an example of whistle

> *He gave a low long **whistle** of surprise.* 
>   
> <sub>[Oxford Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/whistle_1)</sub>

You could say **long** or **prolonged** whistle, as in "*let out a prolonged whistle of admiration.*"

> **prolonged**
>
> *adjective*
>
> Continuing for a long time or longer than usual;
>   lengthy
> <sub>[OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/prolonged)</sub>

Here's an example in a book about golf

> One of the caddies gave a prolonged whistle of surprise and
>   admiration. Who was this new, unknown, and infinitely mild-looking
>   champion who made the club hum through the air like a hornet?
>   <sub>[Google Books: The Greatest Golf Stories Ever Told  By Jeff Silverman](https://books.google.com/books?id=UeVZV2BrHd0C&pg=PA274#v=onepage&q&f=false)</sub>

[Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams) shows an idiomatic construct of the form "*adjective* whistle of *noun*."  The two most common phrases are "low whistle of surprise" and "low whistle of appreciation."

The most common adjectives according to Google Books Ngram are ***low*** and ***long***, both were used in the Oxford Learner's Dictionary example

- ***low***
- ***long***
- slow
- prolonged

the most common noun is the one you are looking for, and the one used in the Oxford Learner's Dictionary example, ***surprise***

- ***surprise***
- appreciation
- admiration
- amazement
- astonishment
- dismay
- incredulity

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had not seen the N-Gram viewer before.  Very cool!

Comment: @EricJ.  I learned about it from someone on this site - learn something every day!

Comment: That is almost certainly the most tightly packed and bewildering Ngram I’ve ever seen!

Answer (score 2):

A [whew](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/whew) can also convey the idea of a surprise:

> - Used to express *surprise*, relief, or a feeling of being very hot or tired:
>     *Whew—and I thought it was serious!*

(ODO)

Answer (score 1):

If it looks as though you might have to find an adjective for your whistle. It'd be one that means the same as "contemplative".

Ah! But there you have it!

> A contemplative whistle

I think this is just fine. And you don't need "long" with it:

> **contemplative**: Expressing or involving prolonged thought: she regarded me with a contemplative eye - *[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contemplative)*

What I really like about "contemplative whistle" is that it takes about the same time to read as it does to make the whistle. You need a longish adjective, I think.